# Multiple paths in Traefik pointing to the same path in backend in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress

Is there a way to make a kubernetes service available under multiple paths via traefik ingress, but sending requests to the backend only with one path?

e.g. `https://example.com/mainpath/api` and `https://example.com/otherpath/api` should both send requests with `/mainpath/api` to the backend

Answer (score 0):

Sure, use two different ingresses, one relatively normal, the other with the `traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /mainpath/api` annotation. Your backend will have to check the `X-Replaced-Path` header if it cares to be able to tell the difference.